# Upload file in selenium without input[type="file=] element

Tags: python-3.x, file, selenium, automation

I am using selenium with python and I am trying to automate a task that requires me to upload a .csv file in a web app. Usually I would find the input[type=file] element and send_keys(path_to_image).

But in this case the element is missing. There is no "browse" button, you can only drag and drop, and only a .csv file.

The box where you drop the file is only a div, with some text. 
While there are 2 input elements, they are of type="hidden" and not interactable.

There is a script, where I can see the data after I have manually uploaded it.

It's contained in a var, named MMContacts.

```
var MMContacts = 
        {
            isDirty: false,
            isFeatureEnabled: true,
            isDisabled: false,
            data: [],
```

And after some functions are defined. 
Ends with:

```
$(MMContacts.init);
```

I was wondering if there would be an easy way to execute some Javascript that would allow me to fill in that data field in MMContacts, or if the only way to automate this is GUI Automation (I know only the very basics of JS)

UPDATE: whole script

```
MMToolbar.next = function()
{
    $("#mm-form input[name=dirty]").val(MMContacts.isDirty);

    if (MMContacts.isDirty)
    {
        var data = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(MMContacts.data));
        data = btoa(data);
        $("#mm-form input[name=data]").val(data);
    }

    $("#mm-form").submit();
}

MMToolbar.prev = function()
{
    // window.history.back();
    window.location = "/mailmerge/settings?id=33053"
}

var MMContacts = 
{
    isDirty: false,
    isFeatureEnabled: true,
    isDisabled: false,
    data: [],

    init: function()
    {
        // arrange
        MMContacts.uploader = $("#uploader");
        MMContacts.grid = $("#grid");
        MMContacts.stats = $("#stats");
        MMContacts.dropzone = $("#uploader,#grid");

        // prepare dropzone
        MMContacts.dropzone.on("dragover", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); });
        MMContacts.dropzone.on("dragenter", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); });
        MMContacts.dropzone.on("drop", MMContacts.dropped);

        // refresh
        MMContacts.render();
    },

    render: function()
    {
        if (MMContacts.data.length == 0)
        {
            MMContacts.uploader.show();
            MMContacts.grid.hide();
            MMContacts.stats.html("");
        }
        else
        {
            MMContacts.uploader.hide();
            MMContacts.grid.show();
            MMContacts.refreshGrid();
            MMContacts.stats.html("Loaded " + MMContacts.data.length + " records - drop new file to replace.");
        }
    },

    dropped: function(e)
    {
        if (MMContacts.isDisabled)
            return;

        if (!e.originalEvent.dataTransfer)
            return;

        if (!e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length)
            return;

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];

        // make sure file format is correct
        /*if (file.type != "text/csv")
        {
            var type = (file.type.indexOf("spreadsheet") > -1) ? "XLSX" : file.type;
            alert("Contact list must be a (CSV) file.\n\nThe file you are uploading is of type (" + type + "). Please open the file in a spreadsheet software (Excel or Google Spreadsheet) and save it as a CSV file.");
            return;
        }*/

        if (!file.name.endsWith(".csv"))
        {
            var type = (file.type.indexOf("spreadsheet") > -1) ? "XLSX" : file.type;
            alert("Contact list must be a (CSV) file.\n\nThe file you are uploading is of type (" + type + "). Please open the file in a spreadsheet software (Excel or Google Spreadsheet) and save it as a CSV file.");
            return;
        }

        // clean/trim file before processing
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(event) {
            var lines = event.target.result.trim().split("\n");
            var data = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
            {
                var line = lines[i];

                // skip if empty line
                if (line.trim().length == 0) continue;

                // skip if only commas
                var clean = line.replace(/\s+/g, "");
                if (clean.length == clean.split(",").length -1) continue;

                data.push(line);
            }

            MMContacts.parseContent(data.join("\n"));
        }

        reader.readAsText(file);
    },

    parseContent: function(data)
    {
        Papa.parse(data, {
            header: true,
            complete: function(results) {

                // validate file is not empty
                if (results.data.length < 0)
                {
                    Modal.alert("The file you chose is empty.");
                    return;
                }

                // restrict non-premium users
                if (!MMContacts.isFeatureEnabled && results.data.length > 20)
                {
                    $("#premium-notice").show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#premium-notice").hide();
                }

                // validate it's not too large
                if (results.data.length > 200)
                {
                    $("#limit-notice #limit-uploaded").html(results.data.length);
                    $("#limit-notice").show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#limit-notice").hide();
                }

                // confirm email is a field
                var header = Object.keys(results.data[0]).map(i => i.toLowerCase() );

                if (header.indexOf("email") == -1)
                {
                    var bracketedHeaders = Object.keys(results.data[0]).map(i => "["+i+"]" );
                    alert("Your CSV doesn't contain an email column. Make sure the name of the column is 'email', lower case, without dashes or extra spaces.\n\nColumns found (check for spaces):\n" + bracketedHeaders.join("\n"));
                    return;
                }

                // all good? set data
                MMContacts.isDirty = true;
                MMContacts.data = results.data;
                MMContacts.render();
            }
        });
    },

    refreshGrid: function()
    {
        // make fields
        var fields = Object.keys(MMContacts.data[0]).map(function(i) {
            return { name: i, type: "text" };
        });

        // add row # field
        fields.unshift({name: "#", type: "text", css: "row-col"});

        var index = 1;
        var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MMContacts.data));

        clone.map(function(i) {
            i["#"] = index++;
            return i;
        });

        // show grid
        MMContacts.grid.jsGrid({
            height: "250px",
            width: "100%",
            data: clone,
            fields: fields
        });
    }
}

$(MMContacts.init);
```

The form part in the html:

```html
<form id="mm-form" method="post">
        <h2>Contacts</h2>
        <span>Populate your target contacts</span>

        <div id="limit-notice">
            A single mail merge campaign is limited to 200 contacts (<a href="https://vocus.io/mailmerge-limit" target="_blank">learn why</a>). 
            The contact list you are trying to upload includes <span id="limit-uploaded"></span> contacts. 
            Consider splitting your contacts into multiple campaigns on different days to avoid the Gmail-imposed daily limit. 
        </div>

        <div id="premium-notice">
            Your plan is limited to 20 contacts per campaign, and no more than three campaigns. Please upgrade to the Starter or Professional Plan. See Dashboard &gt; Billing.
        </div>


        <div id="uploader">
            drop CSV here<br>
            make sure it has an "email" column
        </div>

        <div id="grid" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div id="stats"></div>

        <input type="hidden" name="dirty" value="false">
        <input type="hidden" name="data" value="">

    </form>
```

Comment: Please share html or better url. And html of inputs

Comment: @Sers I have updated with the whole script. It's from Vocus, service for emails. I think you have to install it to see the code. Then if you try to make a mail merge you can see the page I am describing

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue previously, and was able to unhide the input using WebDriver's javascript executor.  Here's how I did it in Java, the python code should be pretty similar.

```
evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('upload').style['opacity'] = 1");
upload(jobseeker.cv()).to(find(By.cssSelector("#upload")));
```

Comment: Thanks! I will translate this and give it a try!

Comment: Here are the 2 input elements 
<input type="hidden" name="dirty" value="false">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="">
There is no element with id=upload... 
Tried to update your code with
browser.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('input').style['opacity'] = 1")
and got
"Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined"
(Note the "s" otherwise I got unknown function)

Comment: Use the `name` attribute  instead.  As name isn't unique you will get a list of elements back.  Here's an example where I grab the first:
`document.getElementsByName("dirty")[0].style["opacity"] = 1`

Comment: Alright that worked without errors. The style property is not set to "opacity: 1;". Now, what is that upload.to?
I am used to upload with send_keys().
And it still says "element not interactable" with send_keys(path_to_file). Tried with both input elements (data and dirty)

Comment: Apologies, on your original question I missed that the input type is hidden.  Change the type to file:
`document.getElementsByName("dirty")[0].type='file'`

Comment: Wow! "Choose file" button appeared, and I was able to upload a file, but the "drop CSV here" box remains blank and I am unable to continue... Feels like the file is there but is not "processed". Again, neither in 'dirty' or in 'data' inputs. Feels like I should call the functions that are defined in MMContacts, but don't know how to do that.

Comment: I have been able to define MMContacts['data'] via browser.execute_script(), and by then calling MMContacts.render(), the information appears in the box. It still doesn't allow me to continue, but now I can play around with the Javascript code until I get it right! Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure I made it. It's surely not the only or best way to do it, but it seems to work. Since I wasn't understanding what was going on with the file, once I uploaded it, I went for MMContacts['data'], and set that in the right format (dictionary, where header row is key, and values are the rows). Then i had to set the property isDirty to true, else it wouldn't work. Finally MMContacts.init(), and then MMToolbar.next().